# Не доходит почта отправленная с помощью PHP

Tags: php, email

Здравствуйте. Привязал почту домена к gmail следуя этой инструкции. Если на почту писать с помощью почтовика (с другого gmail аккаунта, или с mail.ru и т.д.) То на gmail почта доходит нормально. А вот если отправлять с помощью функции mail() на PHP, то письмо на gmail не попадает, а попадает на внутреннюю почту домена на хостинге.

MX записи установил следую инструкции. Вот они:

Hostname    Type    Priority    Value

domain.ru    MX  10  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

domain.ru    MX  20  ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM  
domain.ru    MX  30  ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM  
domain.ru    MX  40  ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
domain.ru    MX  50  ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
domain.ru    MX  60  ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
domain.ru    MX  70  ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COMВ чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: А по времени сколько прошло, может не среплецировался dns?!

Comment: С тех пор как изменили несколько дней прошло. Тем более ведь с обычной отправкой, почта доставляется в gmail нормально, значит получается что все так и MX записи работают. Если я верно все понимаю.

Comment: так надо отключить почту для этого домена на хостинге, как именно зависит от хостинга(шаред/vps, панель там или что, какой почтовый сервер(MTA) используется) и пр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если это не винда, то mail() скорее всего отправляет почту через системный MTA, который у вас настроен на локальную отправку, смотрите настройки почтового сервера.

Answer (score 0):

смотри в сторону **/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf** <br>тебе нужна директива:

> mailhub=localhost <--  тут пропиши то что тебе нужно